# 'Error: line contains NULL byte' when using xlsx2csv tool

Tags: python, csv, xlsx

I'm just trying to convert an xlsx file to a csv file and then read data from that csv file-- I'm using the [xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv/blob/master/xlsx2csv.py) tool, which seems to be legitimate, but I'm getting the error at the bottom of this post, which I frankly don't understand-- aren't restkey and restval supposed to ensure that null keys are filled in? Am I misusing the xlsx2csv tool? Help would be appreciated- thanks!

Here's my code:

```
from xlsx2csv import *
import csv

file_name = 'C:\filepath\file.xlsx'
my_file = open(file_name)
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(my_file.read(1024))
ptc_file.seek(0)

f = open(file_name[:-4]+'csv', "w")
xlsx2csv(file_name, f)
f.close()

dictreader = csv.DictReader(my_file, restkey="filler_key", restval="filler_field",  dialect=dialect)

for row in dictreader:
     print '%s' % row['Field']
```

And when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\filepath\conversiontest.py", line 16, in <module>
      for row in dictreader:
    File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 103, in next
      self.fieldnames
    File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames
      self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
Error: line contains NULL byte
```